# pgfplots legends: propagate styles

Tags: pgfplots

In the following MWE, one would expect that the legend is drawn in the same way specified in the style, but it is not -- it is blue instead of black:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        legend cell align=left,
        legend pos=north east,
    ]
        \addplot+ [
            scatter/classes={
                a={mark=square,black},
                b={mark=square*,black}
            },
            scatter, only marks,
            scatter src=explicit symbolic,
        ]
        table [meta=label] {
             x y label
             0.1 0.2 a
             0.2 0.1  b
        };
        \legend{a,should-be-filled-with-black};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

How to fix this? How to make sure the styles you specify are propagated to the legend? Otherwise I am absolutely loving `pgfplots`.

Comment: Simply remove the `+` after `\addplot` ...

Comment: The distinction is on page 45 of the manual: http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots_unstable.pdf#pgfp.back/addplot